# How to leverage Bootstrap 4 NPM package.json metadata

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm, package.json, node-sass

From the [Bootstrap 4 alpha docs](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#npm):

> Bootstrap’s package.json contains some additional metadata under the following  keys:
>
> - `sass` - path to Bootstrap’s main Sass source file
> - `style` - path to Bootstrap’s non-minified CSS that’s been precompiled using the default settings (no customization)

How would one leverage these keys in development? I can't seem to find any info from NPM on how to access these keys. I'm compiling with `node-sass`, is there a way to leverage these keys so that I could write:

```
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

instead of

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
```

If not, what is the purpose of including these extra keys in `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to leverage the values in the extra keys:

1. **package.json variables**
   You can use the values as variables in your `package.json` scripts. For example, the `sass` directory would be accessible in an `npm` script via the variable `npm_package_sass`.

   You'll find more information on the [documentation page for npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)
2. **Import the package.json file**
   You can require the package.json file and have access to the value stored in the `sass` property:

   ```
   var pjson = require('./package.json');
   console.log(pjson.sass);
   ```